# Google Analytics - How to See More Detailed Browser and OS Info at Same Time?

Tags: google-analytics

I know how to see high-level browser, OS, and device info in Google Analytics.  And I know how to see detailed info *by category* (i.e. IE > IE11, IE10, IE9, etc.).  But how can I see detailed *combinations*?

For example, within the list of OS (from most common to least), I'd like to see specific browser and version (e.g. Chrome 35.x) from most common to least.

I can get these data separately and am wondering if Google Analytics has a way to automatically combine them for me.

Answer (score 23):

Google Analytics only allows two dimensions on standard reports at any one time.   You are asking for a report with three dimensions (OS, Browser, Browser Version).

Starting with the "Operating System" report (from "Audience", "Technology", "Browser & OS"), you can add a secondary dimension of either "Browser" or "Browser Version".

[image: os & browser]

[image: os & browser version]

While neither of those reports do exactly what you want, the latter is pretty close because there is little overlap between browser versions between browser.  I know that "39.0.2383" is a Chrome version, "11.0" is IE, and "34.0" is Firefox.

You can make it work with a custom report.   Click "Customization" and then "+ New Custom Report" from where you can build a report with multiple dimensions like this one:

[image: custom report for four dimensions: os, os version, browser, browser version]

Then it ends up looking like this:

[image: os and browser report]

I really wish that Google Analytics had a "Browser and major version" dimension concept so that you could actually see "Chrome 39" as one entity and as a single second dimension under operating system.

Answer (score 3):

Please create a custom report:

Metrics: Sessions, Users, Pageviews

Dimensions: Opereting System > Browser > Browser Version

Then you've got a report with number of sessions/users/pageviews per browser and you can drill down to see which browser is most popular on selected platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up filters. With that you can pick the major version of the browser and later use it as a dimensions in your reports. Read more here:
[Set up filters for better browser segmentation in GA](https://www.gliffy.com/blog/2012/07/31/more-useful-browser-statistics-from-google-analytics-using-filters/)

Though, it won't help with historical data.

Comment: That link no longer works.  Please post details here rather than just linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Custom reports is one way of doing it. Another is to use the Google Analytics add-on with Google Sheets.