# Google Analytics: how to consolidate browser counts by major version number?

Tags: google-analytics, browsers

In the question "[Google Analytics - How to See More Detailed Browser and OS Info at Same Time?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74609/google-analytics-how-to-see-more-detailed-browser-and-os-info-at-same-time)" the top answer concludes with *'I really wish that Google Analytics had a "Browser and major version" dimension concept so that you could actually see "Chrome 39" as one entity'*

Is there a way to configure a view in Google Analytics that consolidates browser sub-versions (mainly Chrome) as a single entry? Bonus points if the solution allows choice between 0 or 1 decimal places (e.g. whether or not to combine 10.0 and 10.1)

Comment: I wish you could do it.  I download the data and process it with Perl or in a spreadsheet when I want those numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently possible within Google Analytics, but only takes a few short steps to do in excel.

1. In GA, go to Audience > Technology > Browser & OS.
2. Set the secondary dimension to "browser version" and download the report as
   a csv or XLSX.
3. Assuming everything is sitting on Row 1, the following formula will help: =IFERROR(LEFT(B2,FIND(“.”,B2)-1),B2)

[image]

If you want more details on this, check out [this article on Medium.](https://medium.com/@optimiseordie/part-four-the-ultimate-guide-to-using-google-analytics-for-cross-device-optimisation-desktop-988420c719bf)